# How to parse xml and select items to be sent

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I need help on how to do this on Java. There are four transactions inside the xml below. The receiver only accept 3 transactions per send or submit. How can I parse and divide to limit it into 3 per send? Meaning, in the first send are 3 transactions, then next send is 1 transaction. Also, the file is changing, it can be 100 transactions per file.

```
<rc:Record rc:recordID="1010"  rc:grandTotalAmount="1500.00">
<rc:RecordPeriod>000001</rc:RecordPeriod></rc:Report>
<rc:CollectionPerLoc rc:locCode="1111" rc:branchTotalAmount="1500.00">
<rc:RecordToday rc:transDate="2021-03-30">
<rc:Transaction rc:transAmount="200.00"> <rc:TransRefDetails rc:idNumber="001" rc:refNumber="R001" /> 
</rc:Transaction>
<rc:Transaction rc:transAmount="500.00"> <rc:TransRefDetails rc:idNumber="002" rc:refNumber="R002" /> 
</rc:Transaction>
<rc:Transaction rc:transAmount="500.00"> <rc:TransRefDetails rc:idNumber="003" rc:refNumber="R003" /> 
</rc:Transaction>
<rc:Transaction rc:transAmount="300.00"> <rc:TransRefDetails rc:idNumber="004" rc:refNumber="R004" /> 
</rc:Transaction>
</rc:RecordToday> </rc:CollectionPerLoc>
```

Comment: use some xml parser
https://www.baeldung.com/java-xml

Comment: @AnoopLL yeah but how to limit items per submit.

Comment: What I believe is you have 1 xml file with number of transactions and you need to send the xml to a client which accepts only three transactions. In that case open the xml and then create a new xml with 3 transaction send to the receiver and read next 3 create a xml send it like in a loop.

Answer (score -1):

You could use **JAXB**. Please, see more info with examples here https://www.baeldung.com/jaxb